# ROBLOX.Lua Infinite Yeild Possible Fix?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making this tool Wait For "PlaceEvent", but I keep getting this error:

```
21:58:52.024 - Infinite yield possible on 'ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("PlaceEvent")'
21:58:52.026 - Stack Begin
21:58:52.026 - Script 'Players.rohanskywalker.Backpack.Grass.Main', Line 7
21:58:52.026 - Stack End
```

Here is the script:

```
-- Local Script
local tool = script.Parent
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()
local clickEvent = tool.ClickEvent
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local PlaceEvent = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("PlaceEvent")


local function onActivate()
local clickLocation = mouse.hit
clickEvent:FireServer(clickLocation)
PlaceEvent:FireServer()
end

tool.Activated:connect(onActivate)
```

Answer (score 1):

The output you are getting is not an error, but a warning. It is informing you that it is taking a long time for it to find "PlaceEvent" in ReplicatedStorage. There could be a couple causes for this.

**Object isn't created yet**

If you are creating the object in another script or moving the object into ReplicatedStorage, check that it doesn't have a separate error, causing it to abort before creating 'PlaceEvent'

**Object is named Improperly**

If it is being created properly, or it is in ReplicatedStorage from the beginning, check the name to make sure that it is EXACTLY 'PlaceEvent', otherwise your script will yield forever, never finding 'PlaceEvent'.

Those are the two possibilities for that warning, but remember it's only a warning and as soon as it finds that object the script will resume.